# Searching for filenames containing multiple keywords in python

Tags: python

I have a directory containing a large number of files. I want to find all files, where the file name contains specific strings (e.g. a certain ending like '.txt', a model ID 'model_xy', etc.) as well as one of the entries in an integer array (e.g. a number of years I would like to select).

I tried this the following way:

```py
import numpy as np
import glob

startyear = 2000
endyear = 2005

timerange = str(np.arange(startyear,endyear+1))

data_files = []
for file in glob.glob('/home/..../*model_xy*'+timerange+'.txt'):
    data_files.append(file);

print(data_files)
```

Unfortunately, like this, other files outside of my 'timerange' are still selected.

Comment: how about `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()`?

Comment: `glob.glob` also takes regexes, so you should be able to do something like `'/home/..../*model_xy*200*[0-5].txt'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in `glob.glob`. Moreover, `glob.glob` returns a list so you don't need to iterate through it and append to new list.

```
import glob

data_files = glob.glob("/home/..../*model_xy*200[0-5].txt")

# or if you want to do recursive search you can use **
# Below code will search for all those files under /home/ recursively
data_file = glob.glob("/home/**/*model_xy*200[0-5].txt")
```